# OpenGL C++ line disappearing when it rotates close to the camera

Tags: opengl, camera, rotation

I am trying to draw a 3D cube and rotate it.
It draws and it is rotating fine but when a line of the cube(it is not a filled cube) rotates closer to the camera, it slowly disappears and when it rotates away from the camera it slowly draws again.

I tried this to set the camera farther away:

```
glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
```

But it did not worked, nothing was shown on the window.

This are my rendering functions:

```
void drawCube() {
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(angle, 1, 1, 1);

glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
glVertex3f(-0.5f,-0.5f,0.0f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f); //Platform front
glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f); //Platform in the back
glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
glEnd();

angle += 0.005f;

glPopMatrix();
```

}

```
void draw() {
//CLEARING THE SCREEN AND LOAD IDENTITY MATRIX FOR NEW DRAWINGS
glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //BACKGROUND COLOR
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //CLEAR THE SCREEN
glLoadIdentity(); //RESET DRAWING LOCATIONS
glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
drawCube();

SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window.getWin()); //RENDER EVERYTHING TO THE SCREEN
```

}

Does anyone know what is causing the disappearing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what order did you push the matrices ? Did you try pushing the translation before the rotation ?

Comment: Where do you set your projection matrix?

Comment: @genpfault Nowhere I guess. I am new to openGL. where and to which matrix do I have to set ?

Answer (score 1):

My best quess is that your object si clipped on near clipping plane of camera. This is normal effect and it is working correctly. You should try to change your camera properties and observe changes.